# How to make git-diff create a "context" format diff?

Tags: git, diff

I've got a Git repo from which I need to create a patch file in something other than the default [`git diff`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff) format. My use case is I've got a clunky old OSF/1 machine on which I need to apply the patch, and the `/bin/patch` program there doesn't understand unified diffs.

If I use `GIT_EXTERNAL_DIFF=diff`, hoping that I can then use `GIT_DIFF_OPTS=-c` to request a context format diff, then my (modern) `diff` program complains about extra arguments on its command line:

```
diff: extra operand `373e5907b789a1398a91f4ceb4ab14e8a0ed4282'
diff: Try `diff --help' for more information.
external diff died, stopping at [filename].
```

Setting `GIT_EXTERNAL_DIFF=echo` shows that Git seems to run the external diff program with:

```
$GIT_EXTERNAL_DIFF <file2> <file1> <hash> <mode> <tmpfilename> <hash> <mode>
```

This confuses `diff` which doesn't want the extra arguments. Is there an easy way to tell `git diff` to create an old-style "context" format diff?

(My current plan is to write a one-liner shell script that calls the real `diff` with just `$1 $2`, but I'm hoping there is a less awkward way.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Configure a difftool to do what you want:

```
$ git config difftool.ctxdiff.cmd 'diff $LOCAL $REMOTE'
$ git difftool -y -t ctxdiff HEAD~4..HEAD
```

Comment: If we need to get the diff in the context format inbetween 2 commits, where do we need to out the old commit and new commit in, `git difftool -y -t ctxdiff oldCommitHash newCommitHash`

Answer (score 11):

There is no need to configure a custom difftool, just use the -x option:

```
$ git difftool -y -x "diff -c" | less
```

Or configure an alias to make a simple "git cdiff" command output a context-style diff:

```
$ git config --global alias.cdiff 'difftool -y -x "diff -c"'
$ git cdiff | less
```

Comment: can you explain me how to get he context diff of two commits. Lets say that the relevant commit hashes are `b299g2` and `f242g3`?

Comment: why we insert the ` "diff -c" ` as a option