# Convert a context diff to unified diff format

Tags: git, diff

I have received a patch in the context diff format, and I need to apply it in Git. As far as I know, Git can only apply patches that are in the unified diff format.

Is there any way to convert a context diff into unified diff format so that I can then `git apply` the modified patch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `git diff` can only be configured to [*produce* a context diff](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13074326/6309) (or be [filtered to produce one](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/5022B862.2030206%40dunslane.net)), a possible simple approach would be to use [`patch`](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/1-patch/) to apply manually that context diff, then use `git add` to detect the change.

Comment: Thanks for the general approach. I don't think that linked answer is applicable here as it's showing to produce, not how to apply, a context diff?

Comment: @AlexHarvey Right. I have reformulated the anser to keep only the general approach, which is simple enough.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution I've recently found when looking for a solution to the same issue.
Using [quilt](https://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/quilt):

```
dev-util/quilt-0.65::gentoo was built with the following:
USE="-emacs -graphviz" ABI_X86="(64)"
```

from gentoo, and the following command line session, I was able to painlessly
convert a context diff into a unified diff, and adjust the strip level (option -p in patch) from -p0 to -p1 (always use -p1 guys, it will make your and others' lives much easier!)

```
$ tar xf SDL2-2.0.8.tar.gz
$ cd SDL2-2.0.8
$ quilt new SDL2-2.0.8.unified.patch
$ quilt --quiltrc - fold -p 0 < ../SDL2-2.0.8.context.patch # arbitrary -p0 context diff I created for this exercise
$ quilt refresh
# your new -p1 unified diff can be found at SDL2-2.0.8/patches/SDL2-2.0.8.unified.patch
```

Answering this here as this is one of the highest results in google for queries related to converting a context diff to a unified one.

Should work in any distro, I'm just reporting exactly what I have for posterity's sake.

Just found a 'better' way, but requires its own sort of prep work. For this you just need the patch file itself. You will require [patchutils](https://github.com/twaugh/patchutils)

```
dev-util/patchutils-0.3.4::gentoo was built with the following:
USE="-test" ABI_X86="(64)"

$ $EDITOR SDL2-2.0.8.context.patch
# remove all lines like: 1   diff -cr SDL2-2.0.8/src/SDL.c SDL2-2.0.8.new/src/SDL.c (apparently not needed in current git)
# save and quit
$ filterdiff --format=unified < SDL2-2.0.8.context.patch > SDL2-2.0.8.unified.patch
# you can even do this inside vim with
:%!filterdiff --format=unified
```

Hope this helps!